# Spring MVC does not show expected result

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Where is the problem?? Always showing tomcat default page rather than showing test.jsp page

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How dou you call your webpage?? (URL)

Comment: Under <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name> change dispatcher to something else may be SpringDemo1 or something... So when you access it through the browser you call it like  http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo1/, (use the appropriate port number on which your Tomcat is runnin)

Comment: Same result....

Comment: And still no url....

Comment: http://localhost:8080/test.jsp